# Delphi/TZipFile: how to restore the file's original timestamp?

Tags: delphi, zip

Files extracted from a zip using the TZipFile class (I'm using ExtractAll method) get the system datetime as creation/modification file date, but I need to restore the original timestamp, like winzip/winrar do. Can the TZipFile class do it too, or I have to change the files timestamp after?

Comment: AFAIK TZipFile doesn't support restoring file dates or attributes when it's extracting files. You need to do it later

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you are out of luck with the built in ZIP code. It does record the modified timestamp when creating ZIP files. But does not restore it when extracting. And there's no option to make it do so.

I think your best option is to use a third party ZIP component. For example I recommend [tpAbbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/) which does support this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Since Delphi XE6 the [TZipFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Zip.TZipFile) class automatically keeps timestamps and attributes of extracted files ([QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=120635)). So the easiest solution is to upgrade your Delphi to XE6 or newer.

If you cannot upgrade then you need to recover timestamps and attributes after extraction. The original timestamps and attributes are available in the [TZipFile.FileInfos](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.FileInfos) property (array of [TZipHeader](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Zip.TZipHeader)).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14297094)

Comment: In this case the essential part of the answer is "This is fixed in Delphi XE6."